# how to change the amount of java memory heap for Jason-JEdit generated processes? [Linux]

Tags: java, jedit

how to change the amount of java memory heap for Jason-JEdit generated processes?

I'm running code edited in Jason-JEdit, as part of the application a NetLogo process is started, originated by the first one, but a heap size error appears.
The main process in Jason-Jedit is:

user  6006  6003  9 19:44 ?        00:00:02 java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -classpath ~/Jacamo/lib/jacamo.jar:/usr/local/lib/netlogo5.2/NetLogo.jar:. -jar ~/Jason-1.4.2/bin/jedit/jedit.jar

The generated process from Jason-Jedit are:

1-The normal launcher process of the agent

user  6055  6006 11 19:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -classpath ~/Jacamo/lib/ant-launcher.jar org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -e -f bin/build.xml run

2- The NetLogo lauched process

user  6069  6055 99 19:44 ?        00:00:05 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -classpath ~/JaCaMo/workingDir:~/JaCaMo/workingDir/bin/classes:~/Jacamo/lib/jason.jar:/usr/local/lib/netlogo5.2/NetLogo.jar jason.infra.centralised.RunCentralisedMAS systemMAS-JNL.mas2j

As it can be seen the generated processes do not have the heap size option: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m, as the first one process does.

I already tried the following:
1) Edit the jason.sh/Jacamo.sh files adding:
java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -classpath [...]

2) Add the variable _JAVA_OPTIONS in the .profile 
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m"

And this works for the main process only, the Jason-Jedit application, but the problem persist in the generated process. Any idea about how to change the settings in JEdit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with `jEdit` itself, as it is just shipped and used as editor and host for the custom plugin the jason project is providing. From a very short look at the plugin code, I'd say it generates an Ant build script that starts the `RunCentralisedMAS` class and it doesn't inject any jvmargs into this Ant build script. But the `build-template.xml` file has a commented-out line with `jvmarg`s. So I guess if you search for the `build-template.xml` file and change it so that the `jvmarg` are set, it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Vampire, indeed, it was missing, once commented-out the line is seems working as I pretended. Thank you again, I delayed a lot to come to answer the post, sorry about that.